# Referencing a different js file in Yii depending on browser

Tags: php, javascript, yii

I have 2 js files. Although both do the same thing one does not work on IE 7, as such I have 2 different JS files. I need one to be called if the browser is IE7 and the other to be called in all other situations.

I have the standard Yii declaration at the top of the page.

```
<?php
    Yii::app()->getClientScript()->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/js/jquery-1.4.4.js');
    //etc....
?>
```

I have tried the following in the document.ready function.

```
var browserIE7 = (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE 7")>=0) ? true : false;
if(browserIE7){
    Yii::app()->getClientScript()->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/js/IEjquery-1.4.4.js');
}else{
    Yii::app()->getClientScript()->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/js/jquery-1.4.4.js');
}
```

However that does not work. I have never needed to do this before and as such am having difficulty figuring out how to do it.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: PHP is `server side` and runs on the server before the HTML is sent to the client. Your JavaScript is `client-side` and runs after the HTML has been downloaded by the client. It is not possible to execute PHP with a `client-side` script without making a new request to the server (page refresh or Ajax).

Comment: Ah cool, thank you for the explanation George.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you would like for some js hack you can use in your html  as follows to include your script for IE only version

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<script src="http://example.com/js/IEjquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Refer http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/

Answer (score 2):

You've tried to execute php code at your JS? Or I've missed something...

Try to use extension [Browser](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/browser/) and use it in your layout (or somewhere near your `Yii::app()->getClientScript()...` code)

Comment: Although that's what the OP asked for, that's not what he needs. Browser sniffing gets ugly really fast. The conditional statement approach is far cleaner